# navigation between jsf pages within one portlet on WebSphere Portal 8.0

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, websphere, websphere-portal, jsr286

I'm working on WebSphere Portal 8.0 and I am trying to make portlet with few faces.
Can anyone share with me how can I make a simple link to other JSF site within one portlet?
I mean, I was trying to use this, but it doesn't work:

```
<h:outputLink value="page2.xhtml">
    <h:outputText value="take me to the page2" />
</h:outputLink>
```

I'm redirected to the misterious link but I would like to stay on the same site but change face in this single portlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got answer.

If you want use GET, use this:

```
<h:link value="take me to the page2" outcome="page2" />
```

Or by POST use:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{menager.navigateToPage2}" value="take me to the page2" />
</h:form>
```

and in faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>menadzer</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>test.Menadzer</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>symbolAktywnejSpolki</property-name>
        <value>#{param.symbol}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>index.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{menager.navigateToPage2}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>page2</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page2.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

and the class:

```
public class Menager {
    ...
    public String navigateToPage2() {
        return "page2";
    }
}
```

and if you use WebSphere Portal add this, to the faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <view-handler>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FaceletPortletViewHandler</view-handler>
    <resource-handler>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.httpbridge.PortletResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    <el-resolver>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.PortletELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Comment: I added the <view-handler>...ibm.faces20... but I dont know what lib must I add to my project so this can work... Im using maven. Do you know what lib must I use to ? thanks