# navigation between jsf pages in portal not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere-portal

I am developing a small application using jsf in portal websphere, in the doView method of the protlet, i redirect to a jsf page called "edit.xhtml"

```
PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/edit.xhtml");
```

and in the edit page, i have a datatable which displays the names of registered people from the data base (I am using the primefaces datatable).
and i have a link to another page called "index"

```
<h:link outcome="index" value="view all users" />
```

When i press the link, it redirects me to a normal page not the portal page, i mean the header and footer are not displayed in the index page, something like that in the image attached[image: index.xhtml page]

And when i tried to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859884/navigation-between-jsf-pages-within-one-portlet-on-websphere-portal-8-0), and added those lines to the faces-config.xml file

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>edit.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>edit.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

    <application>
        <view-handler>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FaceletPortletViewHandler</view-handler>
        <resource-handler>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.httpbridge.PortletResourceHandler</resource-handler>
        <el-resolver>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.PortletELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
```

the style of primefaces is not applied beside that the index page is displayed as it is not as a portal page.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to portal and couldn't understand you. Anyways, i am using WebSphere Portal V8.0.

Comment: Let me rephrase at least one part: Tried the latest PrimeFaces version?

Comment: I am using primefaces-5.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaServer Faces (JSF), then you should create JSF portlet project (not basic portlet).

Helpful links:

[Custom login portlet](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-login-portlet.html)

[WebSphere Portal v8.0 Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/welcome/wp_welcome.html%23action=openDocument%26content=catcontent%26ct=prodDoc)

Comment: for my understanding... How do you know from the question that this is not the case...